# How to plot timeseries DataFrame by group, and change line type based on condition?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I am wondering how to plot time series in a DataFrame, on the same axis, with different lines for each group. I would also like to change the line type based on some (boolean) condition. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.parser import parse
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.rand(18), 
              'group': ['A']*9 + ['B']*9,
              'future': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]*2}, 
         index=[parse('2018-1-5') + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(9)]*2)
```

The resulting DataFrame:

```
            future group     value
2018-01-05       0     A  0.076445
2018-01-06       0     A  0.800821
2018-01-07       0     A  0.410351
2018-01-08       0     A  0.039647
2018-01-09       0     A  0.664102
2018-01-10       0     A  0.192097
2018-01-11       1     A  0.456182
2018-01-12       1     A  0.163256
2018-01-13       1     A  0.832768
2018-01-05       0     B  0.139014
2018-01-06       0     B  0.265024
2018-01-07       0     B  0.832062
2018-01-08       0     B  0.738957
2018-01-09       0     B  0.334888
2018-01-10       0     B  0.945192
2018-01-11       1     B  0.707845
2018-01-12       1     B  0.135183
2018-01-13       1     B  0.140647
```

Plotting by group is easy enough:

```
df.groupby('group')['value'].plot(legend='True')
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I'd like the lines to become dashed when the corresponding value of `future` is 1.

Here is my attempt at a solution:

```
present_data = df.loc[df['future'] == 0]
future_data = df.loc[df['future'] == 1]

present_data.groupby('group')['value'].plot(legend='True')
future_data.groupby('group')['value'].plot(style='--')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But this is no good. I suppose it could be fixed by manually setting the colors (thought that still leaves the issue of a gap in the line), but surely there is a better way than splitting the DataFrame in two?

Many thanks!

## Edit: Will's solution worked great for me, however I am still wondering how to create the legend properly. I would like two solid lines to appear for groups 'A' and 'B'.

I tried this:

```
legends = []
for idx,grp in df_plot.groupby(['group','future']):
    grp['value'].plot(style=s[grp['future'][0]],color=c[grp['group'][0]])
    if grp['future'][0] == 0:
        legends.append(grp['group'][0])
    else:
        legends.append('')
plt.legend(legends)
```

But this results in dashed lines with no label being added:

[image]

Appending `None` to the legend list doesn't work either. And if I skip appending entirely, 'A' and 'B' don't corresponding to the right lines:

```
legends = []
for idx,grp in df_plot.groupby(['group','future']):
    grp['value'].plot(style=s[grp['future'][0]],color=c[grp['group'][0]])
    if grp['future'][0] == 0:
        legends.append(grp['group'][0])
plt.legend(legends)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make manually specifying color and style a bit easier by combining the grouping into one step, then plotting per group.
To remove the gap, I think you'll need to plot an extra data point.

```
extra=df[df.future==1]
extra = extra[extra.index == min(extra.index)] 
extra['future'] = 0
df_plot = pd.concat([df,extra])


s=['','--']
c={'A': 'red', 'B': 'blue'};

for idx,grp in df_plot.groupby(['group','future']):
    grp['value'].plot(style=s[grp['future'][0]],color=c[grp['group'][0]])
```

[image: no gap plot]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I didn't know you could iterate through the groups like that! One question: is it not simpler, and functionally equivalent to use `extra['future']=0` rather than `extra.loc[:,'future']=0` ?

Comment: a python3 solution could be to using `ggplot`, this allows specifying aesthetics of the graph. like `ggplot(df_plot, aes(x='time', y='value', color='group', linetype='future')) + geom_line()`

Comment: yeah! I had this originally but thought it was too much "getting lost in the weeds".  `...plot(legend='True',label="%s %s"%(grp['group'][0],grp['future'][0]),...`

Comment: Err. that's not any better than what you already have. Sorry. maybe `plot(legend=grp['future'][0] == 0, ...`